# ag-grid text selection and copy is not working for master-detail-custom-detail

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid, master-detail, ag-grid-angular

[ag-grid custom detail Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wfp2r8)

In this example I need to copy "My Custom Detail" or whatever text or content there is based on mouse selection and "ctrl+c".

Now this content is not selectable. Is there a config to add to make it selectable and able to copy that?

Answer (score 1):

In custom component in parent div add this class and add below css, then copy will work.

```
.custom-detail-component {
   user-select: text; /* Allow text selection */
   pointer-events: auto; /* Allow pointer events */
}
```

For EG:
change this to

```
<h1 style="padding: 20px;">My Custom Detail</h1>
```

this

```
<h1 style="padding: 20px;" class="custom-detail-component">My Custom Detail</h1>
```

Then you will be able to select text and ctrl+c will copy the selection